# Database design for user data

Tags: database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am at the early stages of a new project.  As we are developing iteratively and relatively quickly (designing the product as we go), sometimes it can be a little bit harder to pick the "right" design for something up front.  We tend to pick something and re-factor whenever necessary.

Right now I'm working on the model for user data.  My approach is to have essentially 2 tables: one with essential login type data (username, created date, credentials, etc), and the other table to store Key, Value data we need associated with users.

This allows us to be very flexible in the early stages regarding what data we are storing with users.  Provided we don't need complex queries on the data (which we don't yet), this allows for good scalability.

This is also a pattern I have used before.

My big question is, why is this a bad design for the long run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions you should ask are:

- Can we predict all the Keys while designing the application?
- Does our application treat different Keys any differently (i.e. do you have equivalent of `if (Key=="something")` anywhere in your code)?

If you can design your application in advance for all possible keys and your application is treating them all in a specific way, you should just add appropriate columns to the "main" table and stop using the "key-value" table altogether.

If you can predict all keys but you treat some of them generically, you may keep your structure, or alternatively you may move those keys you treat specially into columns of the "main" table and leave the rest in the "key-value" table.

If you cannot predict all the possible keys (i.e. users will have ability to add their own) and even those you can are always treated in a generic way, keep the current structure.

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself:

*"Provided we don't need complex queries on the data (which we don't yet), this allows for good scalability."*

So as soon as you need "complex" queries this will become inefficient, both in terms of elapsed time, and the time required to correctly write the queries themselves.

Maybe you can approach this piecemeal, and migrate some of the key-value pairs to actual table fields as soon as a given subset has been used "in the wild" enough to guarantee it's stable?

In general, the relational model has its strengths, and managing large sets of key-value "pseudofields" is not one of them. For that you may want to go to NOSQL products, maybe.